# how to update table rows using calculated results from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to update SubTotal field in Transactions table by summing up results from bridge table TransactionRecords. Following is what my table contains.

```
|  Transaction  |
| ID | SubTotal |
| 1  |  ???     |
| 2  |  ???     |
| 3  |  ???     |


|     TransactionRecords                      |
| TransactionID | ProductID | QTY | SalePrice |
| 1             |  10       |  4  | 19.99     |
| 2             |  5        |  8  | 9.99      |
| 2             |  3        |  12 | 14.99     |
```

What I want is to have Transaction.SubTotal equal to TransactionRecords.SalePrice * TransactionRecords.QTY where TransactionRecords.TransactionID equals to Transaction.ID

This query :

```
select TransactionID, sum(UnitPrice * QuantitySold) 
from TransactionRecord 
group by TransactionID;
```

gives me each transaction and sale amount made in each transaction and that's the value I want Transaction table to have in it's appropriate ID.

Comment: Please can you give us an example of results you get?

Comment: @jmj Example of what? the query? data in tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Transaction t 
SET SubTotal = (SELECT SUM(UnitPrice * QuantitySold) FROM TransactionRecord tr WHERE tr.TransactionId = t.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks but I found the problem, there were some SUM results were returning null because It didn't had records in TransactionRecords table.